# How does es6 module loading work

Tags: javascript, module, ecmascript-6

I've been [reading](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) [about](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) [es6 module loaders](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader) and I just don't quite understand how it works and am hoping someone can enlighten me.

In the practical workflows link above they have an example like this

```
System.import('app/app').then(function(app) {
  // app is now the Module object with exports as getters
});
```

No problem with that - I get it. But then I see stuff like this

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

and get really confused. What happens if at the time of this call jquery has not yet been transferred to the browser? Does the thread just spin? Does the browser parse your script behind-the-scenes and reform it into a callback like RequireJs does? Is what it does configurable? Are there specific limitations?

Can someone give me a rundown?

Comment: The second thing you see is "CommonJS module loading", not ES6 afaik. It indeed [doesn't work (well) within require.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#cjsmodule)

Comment: @Bergi it works fine within require.js, while I don't prefer it there are certain pages within my current project that use requirejs with the commonjs style. Requirejs scans your script for commonjs expressions and rewrites it to an amd format therefore it is still using callbacks. However, unless I'm mistaken, the es6 proposal does NOT use callbacks - hence my confusion.

Comment: Yes, and scanning the script does not work well for all but the simplest cases. Can you link the part of the ES6 proposal that you mean? `System.import` does obviously use callbacks.

Comment: @Bergi I can't find the module loader proposal period (though I keep reading that there is one and that its close to finalized). But [the es6 module loader](https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader/wiki/A-Brief-ES6-Modules-Overview#all-supported-syntax) for example does exactly this type of thing inside of modules with the import statement. [The require statement above is from them systemjs README](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs#simple-application-structure). I hope you can see why I'm confused.

Comment: You're looking for [\[1\]](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-modules), [\[2\]](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:modules) or [\[3\]](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:module_loaders)? The `import` statements that appear in *module* code are not "synchronous", they are mere declarations and their references are resolved during the load of the module. To actually cause a module load from a *script*, you'd use a module loader like `System.import` with callbacks. The `require` thing of System.js is for backwards-compatibility with Commonjs only.

Answer (score 5):

The ES6 Module Loader will fetch the source, determine dependencies, and wait until those dependencies have loaded before executing the module. So by the time the require executes, the dependency is already sitting there waiting to be executed.

When loading CommonJS through an ES6 module loader, we rely on statically parsing out the require statements from the source, and only executing the source once those requires have loaded.

In this way we can support CommonJS in the browser loaded dynamically. Circular references are treated identically to the way they are handled in Node.

The regular expressions parsing out the require are actually pretty reliable and quick, while taking into account comments and surrounding tokens. See https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/lib/extension-cjs.js#L10 for the one used by SystemJS.

There is one remaining limitation with this approach and that is dynamic and conditional CommonJS requires like `if (condition) require('some' + 'name')` aren't detected properly. This is a necessary cost though to make CommonJS behave as a fully asynchronous module format in the browser.

Comment: Some time after I wrote this question we got [this awesome article on es6 modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html). It directly contradicts some of what you said (ie regex parsing, the way circular dependencies work, and the availability of dynamic requires). It also seems that some of my confusion at least is that modules and module loaders are separate specs of which only the former is complete.

Comment: The ES6 Module Loader has two ways to interpret modules:

1. ES6 modules
2. Legacy module formats
We can build in legacy module format into the ES6 Module Loader through a hook called "instantiate".
You are right - ES6 module loading does have its own circular reference style as well which is different to CommonJS.

When writing CommonJS support into the loader, this can allow full CommonJS-style circular reference support.

In terms of specs, the module loader class behaviour itself is in the ES6 specification, what is a separate specification is the exact environment hooks.